# How to truncate box-sizing:border-box when width is smaller than border-width?

Tags: css

When using `box-sizing:border-box`, borders and paddings are supposed to lay inside the width of a box (says [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) and the [csswg spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#box-sizing)):

```css
p {width: 200px; border: 10px solid red}
```

```html
<p style="box-sizing:content-box">200px + 2 * 10px
<p style="box-sizing:border-box">200px
```

However, when the border-width is larger than the width of the box, the box seems to be pushed to the border-width:

```css
p {width: 0; border: 200px solid red; box-sizing: border-box}
```

```html
<p>
```

*How can this behavior be avoided?* I.e.: how can I force a box to a specified `width` even if I don't have control over the `border-width`?

`overflow:hidden` does not have the effect I hoped for (which makes sense, because `overflow` targets the content, not borders):

```css
p {width: 0; border: 200px solid red; box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden}
```

```html
<p>
```

I can't change the markup, so e.g. setting up a metric decoupling is out of scope:

```css
div {position: relative; width: 0; overflow: hidden}
p {position: absolute; border: 200px solid red}
```

```html
<div><p>
```

*Edit:*

As [Chloe Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12019062/chloe-dev) points out, there is a way: get rid of the border (replace it with an inset box-shadow, although that does not replicate the corners correctly). If there is no other option, I'll have to follow that route. But that's cumbersome for my case: we have a layout cell where the application can set the top/right/bottom/left border separately to 3 values, with borders this leads to 4×3 css rules, but with inset box-shadows this leads to 4×3<sup>4</sup>:

```css
p {width: 0; box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px red}
```

```html
<p>
```

```css
p {width: 200px; height: 48px; box-sizing: border-box}
/* ===== border ============================== */
.border {line-height: 28px}
/* all permutations of .{top,right,bottom,left}-{red,green,blue} can be separate */
.border.top-red {border-top: 10px solid red}
.border.right-green {border-right: 10px solid green}
.border.bottom-blue {border-bottom: 10px solid blue}
.border.left-green {border-left: 10px solid green}
/* ===== shadow ============================== */
.shadow {line-height: 48px; padding-left: 10px}
/* need all permutations of .{top,right,bottom,left}-{red,green,blue} in a single rule */
.shadow.top-red.right-green.bottom-blue.left-green {box-shadow: inset 0 10px red, inset 10px 0 green, inset 0 -10px blue, inset -10px 0 green}
```

```html
<p class="border top-red right-green bottom-blue left-green">with border
<p class="shadow top-red right-green bottom-blue left-green">with shadow
```

Comment: Why are you using a border for this? Any specific reason?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that. So there is a way out, although it is cumbersome in my case. This is the most minimal example I was able to come up with. I'll update my question.

Comment: if you set a border bigger than the width, what kind of result are you expecting? what the browser should do?

Comment: My expectation would be that the width wins over the border-width, i.e. the browser should truncate the box when the width is reached. Thinking about it, you're right that this leads to ugly cases (like where should it start truncating? Left? Right? Center?)